# ffmpeg folder permission unable to find suitable output format

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to make a small shell script using ffmpeg it basically accelerates a video to shorten it and then compresses it.

I was successful into running it into the linux terminal but I am having trouble when i put it in a script i get the unable to find suitable output format error.

The video i use has the format video_year-month-day_hour-minutes-seconds so for example an input video name would be video_2023-07-23_10-48-50.mkv

I pass the name as the first argument to my .sh (video_2023-07-23_10-48-50)

This is my script so far :

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -i "$1".mkv -an -vf "select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,1)',setpts=0.10*PTS" "$1".mp4
ffmpeg -i "$1".mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 "$1"_compressed.mp4
```

and to launch the command i do :

```
sudo bash mybash.sh video_2023-07-28_10-49-50
```

I've tried a chmod 777 on the folder and on the file to no avail.

I've also tried to create an output.mp4 manually and to write in it through the script like so :

```
ffmpeg -i "$1".mkv -an -vf "select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,1)',setpts=0.10*PTS" output.mp4
```

the problem persists.

I'm a bit out of ideas any help is welcome, thanks

Comment: `video_2023-07-28_10-49-50` and `video_2023-07-23_10-48-50` are not the same. My guess is that `video_2023-07-28_10-49-50.mkv` doesn't exist. For testing, try simpler file name like `a.mkv`

Comment: Thank you for your help but that is not it, i've just used it as an example but like i said i runned the command in a terminal with the exact same name and it worked. But same command in a script does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer, turns out when you use notepad++ or another software than basic linux text editor you have to be careful for the end of line characters

so i got to edit -> EOL conversion -> Unix(LF)